# mutt still creating ~/sent file with “set copy=no” in /etc/Muttrc

Tags: linux, mutt

I recently had an issue where a server went down because the / directory was full due to large ~/sent files. I don't need to store these files, so I put in "set copy=no" into the /etc/Muttrc file but it looks like the sent files are still being created. Does anyone know why this is the case and what I can do to remedy the situation?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Result of `mutt -v` and `cat /etc/*-release` below:

```
$ cat /etc/*-release

Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.7 (Tikanga)
$ mutt -v

Mutt 1.5.21 (2010-09-15)
Copyright (C) 1996-2009 Michael R. Elkins and others.
Mutt comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY; for details type `mutt -vv'.
Mutt is free software, and you are welcome to redistribute it
under certain conditions; type `mutt -vv' for details.

System: Linux 2.6.18-274.7.1.el5 (x86_64)
ncurses: ncurses 5.5.20060715 (compiled with 5.5)
libidn: 0.6.5 (compiled with 0.6.5)
hcache backend: This is GDBM version 1.8.0, as of May 19, 1999.
Compile options:
-DOMAIN
-DEBUG
-HOMESPOOL  -USE_SETGID  -USE_DOTLOCK  -DL_STANDALONE  +USE_FCNTL  -USE_FLOCK
+USE_POP  +USE_IMAP  +USE_SMTP
+USE_SSL_OPENSSL  -USE_SSL_GNUTLS  +USE_SASL  +USE_GSS  +HAVE_GETADDRINFO
+HAVE_REGCOMP  -USE_GNU_REGEX
+HAVE_COLOR  +HAVE_START_COLOR  +HAVE_TYPEAHEAD  +HAVE_BKGDSET
+HAVE_CURS_SET  +HAVE_META  +HAVE_RESIZETERM
+CRYPT_BACKEND_CLASSIC_PGP  +CRYPT_BACKEND_CLASSIC_SMIME  -CRYPT_BACKEND_GPGME
-EXACT_ADDRESS  -SUN_ATTACHMENT
+ENABLE_NLS  -LOCALES_HACK  +HAVE_WC_FUNCS  +HAVE_LANGINFO_CODESET  +HAVE_LANGINFO_YESEXPR
+HAVE_ICONV  -ICONV_NONTRANS  +HAVE_LIBIDN  +HAVE_GETSID  +USE_HCACHE
ISPELL="/usr/bin/ispell"
SENDMAIL="/usr/sbin/sendmail"
MAILPATH="/var/mail"
PKGDATADIR="/usr/share/mutt"
SYSCONFDIR="/etc"
EXECSHELL="/bin/sh"
-MIXMASTER
To contact the developers, please mail to <mutt-dev@mutt.org>.
To report a bug, please visit http://bugs.mutt.org/.

$
```

Thanks,

Comment: Try `:` (for `enter-command`) followed by `set ?copy`. What does mutt respond?

Comment: It returns "copy=no". The full mutt command that I'm using (as part of a shell script) is `mutt -e "set content_type=text/html" -s "$sub" $to ${att[*]} < $mes`.

Comment: Well, that does at least tell us that there's no stray setting somewhere else that is taking precedence. Odd. (Of course, the larger question is: Why is a server set up in a way such that filling up a user's home directory brings down the server? But that is not the question you are asking, nor one that strangers on the Internet can answer.) Next question: Which exact version of mutt are you running? Please [edit] your question to show the output of `cat /etc/*-release` and `mutt -v`.

Comment: I've added it to the question.

Answer (score 2):

add this is `~/.muttrc`:

```
set copy = no
set folder = ""
```

Comment: I tried this and it works for me (stopping a copy being append to ~/sent) on mutt v1.10.1.

Comment: Weird.... In 2019 I didn't use mutt. And I also had much less knowleadge about OS and getting information for programs. Is this really my answer? If so, I must always have been a genious compared to some.